# How to convert DJVU file into PDF

Tags: pdf, converters, djvu

There are many books available only in DJVU format where text is selectable and size is quite small (300 pages less than 5 MB).
Since DJVU viewers are poor in terms of annotation of files, I want to convert them into PDF.

**What are the options to convert DJVU book into PDF that maintains selectable text and does not result in a huge (x10 larger) PDF file?**

Comment: Probably most of the developers who are maintaining djvu-to-pdf converters don't know about the fact that djvu format supports text objects...

Answer (score 2):

since this question did not get answered so far:

I recommend to use the following online converter which to my knowledge is the only one to fulfill the two criteria: [djvu to pdf](https://www.djvu-pdf.com). However, I do not know any stand-alone converter achieving this goal.